# ng-change and custom directive makes scope variable undefined while initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm exploring angular custom directive with `ngModel`. I want to understand the flow of execution and about scopes so I'm not getting following things that why it's giving me unexpected values.

- Why `myVar` is undefined when ng-change called by directive?
- Is it required to set value from directive in jQuery style before calling $setViewValue?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myVar"  ng-change="changeMe()" my-custom-dir/> 

    <button>{{myVar1}}</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).controller("myCtrl",["$scope",function($scope) {
    console.log("myvar defined");
    $scope.myVar = "jay";

    $scope.changeMe = function() {
        $scope.myVar1 = $scope.myVar;
        console.log($scope.myVar)
    }
}]).directive("myCustomDir",[function(){
    return {
        require:"ngModel",
        link:function(scope,ele,attr,ctrl) {
            console.log(ele);

            ele.val("he")
            //scope.$apply(function() {
            ctrl.$setViewValue();
           // });
        }
    }
}]);
```

[JSFiddle Showing my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/37kXt/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code myVar is not linked to directive. If you want to manipulate a directive scope - you have to define isolated scope in the directive. And it not good to use jquery to update the scope variable  when angularjs takes care of that automatically for you.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/iamgururaj/37kXt/2/

**Directive:**

```
directive("myCustomDir",[function(){
    return {
        scope:{
            model:"=ngModel"
        },
        link:function(scope,ele,attr,ctrl) {
            scope.model = 'he';
        }
    }
}]);
```